# How do we check this probability estimate?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let us assume that it has been given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega),\mathbb{P})$. We are asked to prove

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right) \geq 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A^{c}_{k})
\end{align*}

Analogously, if we assume that $\mathbb{P}(A_{k}) \geq 1 - \epsilon$, for $1\leq k\leq n$, then we are asked to prove

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right) \geq 1 - n\epsilon
\end{align*}

No restrictions are imposed to $A_{k}$ other than $A_{k}\in\mathcal{P}(\Omega).$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Even though I do not know how to prove the first relation, I am able to prove the second as a corollary:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A_{k})\geq 1 - \epsilon \Longrightarrow -\mathbb{P}(A^{c}_{k}) \geq -\epsilon \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}\right) \geq 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A^{c}_{k}) \geq 1 - n\epsilon
\end{align*}

Any hints on the first case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the union bound
$$P \left(\bigcup_k A_k^c\right) \le \sum_k P(A_k^c)$$
and note that $$\left(\bigcup_k A_k^c\right)^c = \bigcap_k A_k$$